# Can True and False be represented without quantifies?

Tags: logic

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Logical_symbols

> Sometimes the truth constants T, Vpq, or ⊤, for "true" and F, Opq, or ⊥, for "false" are included. **Without any such logical operators of valence 0, these two constants can only be expressed using quantifiers.**

- How can True and False be represented without quantifies?
- Can True and False be represented without quantifies, e.g. $\tilde{p} ∨ p$ and $\tilde{p} ∧ p$? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The bolded sentence you quote from Wikipedia is wrong -- true and false can indeed be represented as $\neg p\lor p$ and $\neg p\land p$ for any well-formed-formula $p$. In some logics, such as intuitionistic logic, $\neg p\lor p$ may not be unambiguously true, but then at least $p\to p$ will be.

The only way to make the sentence true would be to somehow prevent there from being any wff $p$ you could use in these constructions in the first place -- such as if

- The language we're working in contains no propositional letters (nullary predicates), and no individual constants (nullary function letters), *and*
- For some reason we require that everything we write down is a *sentence* (without free variables).

In which case, expressing $\bot$ and $\top$ requires quantifiers for the trivial syntactic reason that one needs quantifiers to be allowed to say *anything at all* in the first place.

Comment: I agree the issue is whether we want to represent $\top$ and $\bot$ by arbitrary formulas, or by sentences - in the specific case of a theory in which every sentence has quantifiers. ZFC is an example of such a theory.  It's also the case that the sentence in question from Wikipedia precedes the discussion of non-logical symbols.